# use label row to build pandas df column

Tags: pandas, datetime

How turn a csv build like this to a DF with "var" as column??

```
Date             var         bv    value
2000-01-01       Tmin        RO1   12
2000-01-01       Tmax        RO1   32
2000-01-01       Tmin        RO2   23
2000-01-01       Tmax        RO2   22
2000-01-02  ….
```

I expect:

```
Date             Tmin    Tmax    bv    
2000-01-01       12       32     RO1   
2000-01-01       23       22     RO2   
2000-01-02  ….
```

I try but use for loop and Im sure we can do it more pythonic...

Comment: Im the true data novice...

Comment: Absolutely not, that's my title :) life is learning enjoy the ride!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, we can use `pd.crosstab`

```
new_df = pd.crosstab(
    [df["Date"], df["bv"]], df["var"], values=df["value"], aggfunc=lambda x: x
).reset_index()

print(new_df[['Date','Tmin','Tmax','bv']])


var        Date  Tmin  Tmax   bv
0    2000-01-01    12    32  RO1
1    2000-01-01    23    22  RO2
```